# App can be built with maven, but not as Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2e

I have an Android project which I ¨mavenized¨ (Configure > Convert to Maven Project) using the M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse.
The project uses a google play services library, which was transformed into an apklib. I added this dependency to my project (to my pom.xml). I have to mention that the pom was build automatically, but I replaced it with the one generated by :

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

After that I did a clean install and built the project with maven, having the following goals in run config:

```
clean install -Dandroid.sdk.path="path to my sdk" android:deploy android:run
```

Everything works fine, but I have errors in my project(so I can't run it as an Android app). It looks like everything related to the google library is not recognized.
My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MyProject</groupId>
<artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MyProject</name>
<!-- <packaging>apk</packaging> --> <!-- if i try to add packaging it will give an error --> 
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.air</groupId>
        <artifactId>googleplayair</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.crashlytics</groupId>
        <artifactId>crashlytics</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>/User/Documents/eclipse/cruzcampo-android/app/cruzcampo/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/User/Documents/eclipse/MyProject/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/User/Documents/eclipse/MyProject/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/User/Documents/eclipse/MyProject/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/User/Documents/eclipse/MyProject/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>/User/Documents/eclipse/MyProject/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>/User/Documents/eclipse/MyProject/src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/User/Documents/eclipse/MyProject/target</directory>
    <finalName>MyProject-1.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- </plugins> -->
            <!-- </pluginManagement> -->
            <!-- <plugins> -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testResources</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testResources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-site</id>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>site</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>/User/Documents/eclipse/MyProject/target/site</outputDirectory>
                            <reportPlugins>
                                <reportPlugin>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                                </reportPlugin>
                            </reportPlugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>site-deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>/User/Documents/eclipse/MyProject/target/site</outputDirectory>
                            <reportPlugins>
                                <reportPlugin>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                                </reportPlugin>
                            </reportPlugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>/User/Documents/eclipse/MyProject/target/site</outputDirectory>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <reportPlugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        </reportPlugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>
                    com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2
                </groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>

                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>

</build>
<reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/User/Documents/eclipse/MyProject/target/site</outputDirectory>
</reporting>
```

I guess that right now Maven is working fine, but there is a problem with Android.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse ADT does not support the Maven archive format for `apklib` dependencies. In order for this to successfully compile in Eclipse you need to have the full source of a "Mavenised" (i.e. contained a POM with matching Maven coordinates to the dependency declared in your app POM) Android Library project imported into your Eclipse workspace.